# How to display next and previous month via PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, loops, calendar

I simply want to add the functionality for this array to display the next month on click. It currently shows all the days in the current month.

my code :

```
  <?php
      $workdays = array();
      $type = CAL_GREGORIAN;
      $month = date('n'); // Month ID, 1 through to 12.
      $year = date('Y'); // Year in 4 digit 2009 format.
      $day_count = cal_days_in_month($type, $month, $year); // Get the amount of days
      $next_date = date('n', strtotime($month .' +1 month'));
      $prev_date = date('n', strtotime($month .' -1 month'));
      //loop through all days
      for ($i = 1; $i <= $day_count; $i++)
      {
        $date = $year.$month.$i; //format date
        $get_name = date('l', strtotime($date)); //get week day
        $day_name = substr($get_name, 0, 3); // Trim day name to 3 chars
        //if not a weekend add day to array
        if($day_name != 'Sun' && $day_name != 'Sat')
        {
          $workdays[] = $i;
         }
      }
      foreach ($workdays as $workday => $test) {
        echo $test;

     }
   ?>
```

outputs :

```
3 4 5 6 7 10 11 12  13 14 17 18 19  20  21  24  25  26  27  28
```

I need something like this :

```
  <a href="?date=<?=$prev_date;?>">Previous month</a>
    <a href="?date=<?=$next_date;?>">Next month</a>
```

Comment: In which format do you need these values? How should it looks like?

Comment: _Small Suggestion_ Do `date('D', strtotime($date));` then you dont need to trim as it is already a 3 char day

Comment: Hi @AksenP , I don't really care. I have an array with all the current days of the month minus saturday and sunday. Just want two buttons that gives the option to display the next months days and previous months days. Just like my output i showed in the original question

Comment: @RiggsFolly My bad I had the wrong output. Changed it now to the actual output. So current month minus sat and sun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, you need to display some links to the working days of the current month and a link to the previous and next months.

> The below code requires **PHP5.4** or higher.

The following function will return links to working days in a month:

```
const DATE_FOMAT = 'Y-m-d';
const LINK_SEPARATOR = " | ";

// get the reference date from the Query string so that we can print the calendar for any month
$refDateStr = $_GET['dt'] ?? date(DATE_FOMAT); // this requires PHP 7.1 or above

// this function will return the links to all working days
// in the given month (based on the $refDateStr)
function getDateLinks($refDateStr) {
    try {

        // first we check if the given date is valid or not
        $refDateDt = date_create_from_format(DATE_FOMAT, $refDateStr);

        if (!$refDateDt || $refDateDt->format(DATE_FOMAT) !== $refDateStr) {
            // date is not valid. We cannot proceed with this date
            throw new Exception('Invalid date supplied. Dates should be in ' . DATE_FOMAT .'.');
        }

        // now lets find first and last days of the given month
        // for convenience, the start date is set to the last date of past month
        $startDate = new DateTime($refDateDt->modify('first day of this month')->format(DATE_FOMAT));
        $startDate->sub(new DateInterval("P1D"));

        $endDate = new DateTime($refDateDt->modify('last day of this month')->format(DATE_FOMAT));

        $dateLink = null;
        // lets create the date links
        while ($startDate < $endDate) {
            $startDate->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
            // exclude weekends... :-)
            if (in_array($startDate->format('D'), ['Sat', 'Sun']))
                continue;
            $dateLink .= getDateLinksFormated($startDate);
        }
        return rtrim($dateLink, LINK_SEPARATOR);
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        echo $exception->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Let's decide how to show the date links

```
// This function create the date links
function getDateLinksFormated(DateTime $dt):string 
{
    return sprintf(
        "<a href='?%s'>%s</a>%s",
        $dt->format(DATE_FOMAT),
        $dt->format('d'),
        LINK_SEPARATOR
    );
}
```

Now it's time to show your calendar!!!

```
// Link to the past month
echo "<a href='?dt=" . date(DATE_FOMAT, strtotime('-1 month', strtotime($refDateStr))) . "'><< PREV MONTH </a>";

// Link to the next month
echo getDateLinks($refDateStr);

// Link to the next month
echo "<a href='?dt=" . date(DATE_FOMAT, strtotime('+1 month', strtotime($refDateStr))) . "'> NEXT MONTH >></a>";
```

> Read more about PHP DateTime Class [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.  Typo questions are preferably closed because they are unlikely to help researchers.

Comment: @mickmackusa I will surely try to improve my answer. Thanks

Comment: Actually, I don't think this post attempts to answer the question.  The OP wants prev and next buttons.

Comment: Hey @invalidbot thanks! I knew about that method. How could I translate that into a button. And also preferably in combination with my current code. :D

Comment: @Gago in which format you need the date? Without any separators (202021, 202022, 2020229)???

Comment: 2020221 (2020/2/21) (Y-d-m) . Like this. Is that what u mean? @invalidbot

Comment: I have made an edit to my answer, but it partially answers your question. From my understanding you want the working days (not the weekend dates) from past/next month. Right?

Comment: I already got the current working days. I only want the option to show the next month. Just like a calendar , you understand?  We are in Feb right now So my output is :
"3 4 5 6 7 10 11 12  13 14 17 18 19  20  21  24  25  26  27  28"  then i want a button that says ' previous month / next month ' and when someone clicks on that the previous month / next month is displayed. @invalidbot

Comment: @Gago I have updated my answer with a code to accomplish this. Hope this could be a help.

Comment: @invalidbot This is exacly what I needed. Thank you so much! I really appreciate the effort you put into this.

Comment: Glad to know that it helped you!